# Jquery CSS float with absolute positioning after append

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to place an image icon over a `div`. Whatever the `position` of the `div`, the image icon would be there as the image icon `css position` is governed by the `div absolute position`:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function( $ ) {
var divname1= '.mydiv';

var position = $(divname1).offset(); 

$('#myicons').css(position);
$(divname1).append('<div id="myicons"><a href="#"><img src="http://test.tld/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/resources/img/myicons.png"></a></div>');


});
```

It works perfectly except the problem is that it occupies space and distorted the existing `div` after appending to the `div` where it will be placed. I would like to float it over the target `div` (e.g. `divname1`) after appending so as not to alter the existing `divname1` layout.

Do you have ideas?

Comment: how about not 'appending' the new div to the original one?  just create the new div, and use the position data from the original to position it in the same spot (maybe with a z-index to ensure it stays on top).

Also, I recommend using an id, not a class, for identifying your 'mydiv' div

Comment: I find the append method more flexible as I have a lot of divs that would be appended with these icons that depends on their position. And these JS code would be created by a PHP script in the server side. If I can only float these icons over these divs, it would be perfect.Thanks for your suggestion on using an id, I will try i and also your other options on using z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line of code check if this works.

```
$('#myicons').css('display','inline');
```

Comment: I have tried adding the above line after this: $('#myicons').css(position); and it does not float over the existing div after appending. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: do one thing try to call this $('#myicons').css(position); before });

Comment: I didn't get your point clearly. Do you mean adding your suggestion before $('#myicons').css(position);? Yes I have tried it, and the icons is not floating over the div.

Comment: Add this $('#myicons').css(position); after this $(divname1).append('<div id="myicons"><a href="#"><img src="http://test.tld/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/resources/img/myicons.png"></a></div>');